# trouble in adding twbs:bootstrap into Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, web-development-server

> C:\Users\HP\demo_app>meteor add twbs:bootstrap  => Errors while adding
>   packages:
>
> While selecting package versions: error: Potentially incompatible
>   change required to top-level dependency: jquery 1.11.11, was
>   3.0.0. Constraints on package "jquery":
>   * jquery@1.11.9 || 3.0.0 <- blaze 2.3.4 <- blaze-html-templates 1.1.2
>   * jquery@1.0.1 <- twbs:bootstrap 3.3.6
>
> To allow potentially incompatible changes to top-level dependencies,
>   you must pass
>   --allow-incompatible-update on the command line.

Comment: Quite vague information. Better to add a more details.

Answer (score 2):

I got same error yesterday while adding bootstrap package to meteor. After research what I did was....

First,removed existing version of jquery....

> meteor remove jquery 3.0.0

then,added old version of jquery...

> meteor add jquery@1.11.11

then,added bootstrap...

> meteor add twbs:bootstrap

This steps worked for me.You can try them.Please let me know if it works for you also.
Thanks.